# Start page option is incorrect. Pagination plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the plugin twbs-pagination. Uncaught Error: Start page option is incorrect.

```
 function paginationInit(pages) {
    var current = 1;
    paginationItem.twbsPagination('destroy');

    paginationItem.twbsPagination({
        totalPages: pages,
        visiblePages: 5,
        next: 'Next',
        prev: 'Prev',
        startPage: current,
        hideOnlyOnePage: true,
        initiateStartPageClick: false,
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            var target = $('#label-search');
            index = page - 1;
            current = page;

            $('.background-target').css({
                'height': heightResult
            });

            target.trigger('submit');

        }
    })
}
```

I tried to console.log all variables, and all doing fine. Have any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Which line is that error being thrown on? Many of the other solutions point to destroying the pagination, which you're already doing, I just wonder if destroying it before it exists could be the issue.

Comment: Its working, maybe paginationItem is vanilla js object in your case ? Plugin needs  a jQuery object.

Comment: the error is "start page option is incorrect". paginationItem is just jquery selector

Answer (score -1):

The value of startPage must an Integer Value

Try this:

```
    function paginationInit(pages) {
    var current = 1;
    paginationItem.twbsPagination('destroy');

    paginationItem.twbsPagination({
        totalPages: pages,
        visiblePages: 5,
        next: 'Next',
        prev: 'Prev',
        startPage: parseInt(current),
        hideOnlyOnePage: true,
        initiateStartPageClick: false,
        onPageClick: function (event, page) {
            var target = $('#label-search');
            index = page - 1;
            current = page;

            $('.background-target').css({
                'height': heightResult
            });

            target.trigger('submit');

        }
    })
}
```